# Cannot use a custom PHP plugin in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, namespaces

I have installed a plug-in called tet. I copied `tet.so` in the plug in folder and included it in `php.ini`

I have checked phpinfo and says that the plugin is enabled and running.

I have created a php page to test it.

```
<?php
new tet();
?>
```

And works perfectly.

However when I try this on my laravel it gives me this error:

> FatalThrowableError in mycontroller.php line 16: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\tet' not found

tet is not a controller. Tet is a class created by the php plugin. How do I include this in laravel?

Comment: Try "new \tet();"

Comment: @Amarnasan This actually worked. You might want to say this as answer so I can check you.

Comment: Ok, done, glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
new \tet();
```

because you are using it inside a namespace. Inside a namespace any reference to a class is considered as relative to the namespace you are in. With the "\" you can "escape" the namespace and so you can access classes outside.